# DNSMasq - Different Responses for Specific MAC Addresses

Tags: linux, centos, dnsmasq

Anyone know of a way for me to setup a separate host file, or send different responses, from DNSMasq to specific PCs on my network?

Specifically, if I wanted to block youtube, or facebook, or etc. from my child's computer at MAC ab:cd:00:01:02:03, my thought is to add entries in the DNSMasq host file such as:

127.0.0.1    facebook.com, youtube.com

But I would not want to block these for the entire family, only for his/her computer.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

DNSMasq conditional capability rely mostly on its tagging mechanism and it is only related to its DHCP side.

One solution would be to first use the DHCP side of DNSMasq to *tag* which host is "child" and which is "grownup":

```
# grownup network
dhcp-host=11:22:33:44:55:66,host01,192.168.1.11,infinite,set:grownup
dhcp-host=66:55:44:33:22:11,aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff,host02,192.168.1.12,infinite,set:growup

# child network
dhcp-host=ab:cd:00:01:02:03,child01,192.168.1.21,infinite,set:child
```

So, conditionally set `dhcp-option` to attribute a specific DNS resolving chain to "grownup" hosts (assuming `10.10.10.1` and `10.10.10.2` are your DNS servers and `192.168.1.2` is your DNSMasq box IP address):

```
# options
dhcp-option=tag:grownup,option:dns-server,10.10.10.1,10.10.10.2
dhcp-option=tag:child,option:dns-server,192.168.1.2
```

From there, "grownup" host will directly resolv through your ISP DNS and the "child" ones would use DNSMasq resolving chain (or any other DNS server sitting on your DNSMasq box).

Finally adding a few `host-record` or a `addn-hosts` option:

```
host-record=www.facebook.com,127.0.0.1
```

For more about about DNSMasq:

- [DNSMasq man](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html)