# DNSmasq - MAC address-based responses for both IPV4 and IPv6

Tags: dnsmasq

I have my own dhcp server with dnsmasq on a network wit both IPv4 and IPv6. Everything has been working fine. Now I would like to it to offer different DNS Server addresses than the default for my wife's computer, based on her MAC address.

I was able to do it on IPv4 (see below), but IPv6 continues to point to my dhcp server.

I've read [DNSMasq - Different Responses for Specific MAC Addresses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328260/dnsmasq-different-responses-for-specific-mac-addresses) and it is a good start, but the bugaboo is that the IPv6 server address hasn't changed.

Under /etc/dnsmasq.d I created 03-bypass.conf and it's working thus:

```
dhcp-option=tag:googledns1,6,8.8.4.4,8.8.8.8
dhcp-host=AB:CD:EF:88:77:66,set:googledns1
```

On my wife's computer, the DNS servers are as shown above (8.8.4.4 and 8.8.8.8). But there's also the IPv6 entry which is my dhcp server.

I tried this:

```
dhcp-option=tag:googledns2,option6:dns-server,[2001:4860:4860::8888]
dhcp-host=AB:CD:EF:88:77:66,set:googledns2
```

But it didn't seem to make a difference. As a matter of fact, with only that option, or even with both sets in place, those customizations seem to be ignored (her DNS servers are set to my DHCP/DNS server for both IPv4 and IPv6). But the dnsmasq daemon does not show any errors or warnings.

Any ideas? I have yet to find any discussion of this issue online. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else coming to this post, it looks like you are trying to assign an IPv6 DNS server address to an IPV4 MAC address, you will need to assign it to an IPV6 interface id

Comment: Oh geez. Duh. Well I've dropped this work, but that is a pretty obvious thing! I'll bet you're right.